# fancybox jquery,css not applying after popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox

I want to set fancybox top position on where user clicked, 
Means if i click on body at 300px from top, then need to set fancybox `top:300px`.

**what i tried is:**

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    'onComplete': function() {
      $(".fancybox-wrap").css({'top':'20px', 'bottom':'auto'});
    }
});
```

But thats not working, after that i tried:

```
$('.fancybox').click(function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    $(".fancybox-wrap").attr('style','top:' offset.top +'px !important');
    $(".fancybox-wrap").css({'top':'20px', 'bottom':'auto'});
});
```

But not working, can anyone help me on this?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(".fancybox-wrap").css({'top !important':'20px', 'bottom':'auto'});

Comment: tried that also, but not working

Answer (score 1):

Just Try single line ,

```
$(".fancybox-wrap").css('top','20px');
$(".fancybox-wrap").css('bottom','auto');
```

Hope this help